# How to add "Add to cart" function for post with type is 'post' in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have already added "Add to cart" button (for post with type = post) with same POST end point like "Add to cart" function in the post (with type = product), but cannot working properly, like that:

```
    <?php
    add_filter('woocommerce_get_price','reigel_woocommerce_get_price',20,2);
    function reigel_woocommerce_get_price($price,$post){
        if ($post->post->post_type === 'post')
        $price = get_post_meta($post->id, "price", true);
        return $price;
     }
    add_filter('the_content','rei_add_to_cart_button', 20,1);
    function rei_add_to_cart_button($content){
        global $post;
        if ($post->post_type !== 'post') {return $content; }

        ob_start();
        ?>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input name="add-to-cart" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $post->ID ?>" />
            <input name="quantity" type="number" value="1" min="1"  />
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Add to cart" />
        </form>
        <?php

        return $content . ob_get_clean();
    }
    ?>
```

Reference: http://reigelgallarde.me/programming/how-to-add-custom-post-type-to-woocommerce/

Thank you for your support!